# Intellij feature Rerun failed Test giving error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber-java

I am running cucumber test cases in bulk. 
Suppose I have 5 feature files to run in bulk and one failed out of it. 
So in next execution I'm trying to run failed test cases, for that I'm trying to use Intellij provided feature, i.e.  Rerun failed Test. So when I click on it, it gives me below error.

Error:
0 test classes found in package 'test.java'
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -'path of JAVA_TOOL_OPTION'

Process finished with exit code -2
Empty test suite.

Comment: Sound like [IDEA-210029](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210029) Could you attach a sample project to that issue to look into?